# List of Pojo not getting converted into Json using @ResponseBody

Tags: java, json, spring

I have controller class as below:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/Reporting/FilterAsJson", method =    RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody  PagedQueryResult<GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult>    filterAsJson(@ModelAttribute GetEntitleReportQuery query, HttpSession  session)

       {
        getEntitlementOverviewFromSession(session).updateFromQuery(query,   session);
            return  queryDispatcher.dispatch(query);}
```

The POJO class GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult is :

```
public class GetEntitlementOverviewReportResult 
          {  
          private Long id;
          private String customerName;
          private Long customerId;
          private String customerNumber;
          private String createdOn;
          private String itemCreationDate;
          private String licenseStatus;
          private String licenseType;
          private String licenseStatusCode;
          private String licenseID;
          private Long requestId;
          private String licenseRootID;
          private String customerNameCS;
          private String customerNumberCS;
         // <with getters and setters for the variables>
          }
```

The problem is when all the fields in bean class is being set, proper Json is getting returned as a response. But when only first 6 fields are  getting set, the response fails with 500 error in the debugger tool and doesn't return back to the calling ajax method. I get an "internal error" pop up in the browser. What am i missing here? Is is not possible to leave out the other fields whose values are not being fetched? I also tried using @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace of the internal error?

Comment: is this spring framework or spring boot? you might need to add the jackson http message converter bean to the xml configuration.

Comment: include the stack trace so we can figure it out

Comment: This is Spring framework. No stack trace is generated. Browser just gives  Internal error pop up and the response fails.

Comment: the xmlHttp response is as below:</head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR
 size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description
</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
</p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3></body></html>